# Making symmetrical matrix of characters

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of characters:

```
mat1
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "0"  "B"  "A"  "C"  "D"  "D" 
[2,] "0"  "0"  "B"  "C"  "C"  "C" 
[3,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "D"  "D"  "C" 
[4,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "B"  "B" 
[5,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "A" 
[6,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"
```

I want to have a Symmetrical matrix of that, as below:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "0"  "B"  "A"  "C"  "D"  "D" 
[2,] "B"  "0"  "B"  "C"  "C"  "C" 
[3,] "A"  "B"  "0"  "D"  "D"  "C" 
[4,] "C"  "C"  "D"  "0"  "B"  "B" 
[5,] "D"  "C"  "D"  "B"  "0"  "A" 
[6,] "D"  "C"  "C"  "B"  "A"  "0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the lower triangular part of the matrix as equal to the lower triangular part of the transposed matrix, by using the `lower.tri` functions on the matrix `mat1`:

```
mat1[lower.tri(mat1)] <- t(mat1)[lower.tri(mat1)]
```

Comment: you're right, my mistake. pls see corrected. this question is a duplicate, for example, of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165320/creating-a-symmetric-matrix-in-r).